# Discontinuity in RaycastHit.textureCoord values (getting coordinates on texture right)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, coordinates

Hi I'm trying to get a particular coordinate on texture (under mouse cursor). So on mouse event I'm performing:

```
Ray outRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit clickRayHit = new RaycastHit();

if (!Physics.Raycast(outRay, out clickRayHit))
{
    return;
}

Vector2 textureCoordinate = clickRayHit.textureCoord;

Texture2D objectTexture = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture as Texture2D;

int xCord = (int)(objectTexture.width * textureCoordinate.x);
int yCord = (int)(objectTexture.height * textureCoordinate.y);
```

But the problem is that the coordinate I'm getting is not preciesly under the cursor but "somewhat near it". And it's not like coordinates are consistently shifted in one way but shifting is not random as well. They are shifted differently in different points of the texture but:
they remain somwhere in the area of real cursor
and coordinates shifted in the same way when cursor is above the same point.

Here is part of coordinates log: http://pastebin.ca/3029357

If i haven't described problem good enough I can record a short screencast.

GameObject is a Plane.

If it is relevant mouseEvent is generated by windows mouseHook. (Application specific thing)

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:** I've decided to record screencast - https://youtu.be/LC71dAr_tCM?t=42. Here you can see Paint window image through my application. On the bottom left corner you can see that Paint is displaying coordinates of the mouse (I'm getting this coordinates in a way I've described earlier - location of a point on a texture). So as I move mouse cursor you can see how coordinates are changing.

**UPD2:**
I just want to emphasize one more time that this shift is not constant or linear. There could be "jumps" around the mouse coordinates (but not only jumps). The video above explains it better.

Comment: mouse coordinates log will not help any of us. it would help if you tell what are your Canvas settings in the editor: is it constant pixel size or does it scale with screen size? most of these problems are solved with correcting the scale. try to use Debug.Log to write the values of objectTexture.width , textureCoordinate.x , objectTexture.height , textureCoordinate.y

Comment: I'm not using Canvas here. Just a standard 3d object - plane with texture on it. objectTexture.height/width remain the same throughout the program execution. Jumps are occuring in the values of textureCoordinate

Comment: Sorry, I read: "GameObject is a Panel." My mistake. Is your 3D object scaled on any axis?

Comment: Yes it is scaled on x and z axes.

Comment: try to run it with scale of 1 and you will see if that is the problem. if it is, you will have to multiply textureCoordinate with object scale.

Comment: I've tried it and got pretty much the same strange behaviour. I think if it were scale problem it would be misplaced in some ordered way. But as I said this is not the case.
I've added screencast to the question description.

Comment: i see now. i imagined that the "coordinate shift" is constant or linear. then i read your coordinate log again and saw the "jump" lines. you should edit your question and tell people that the "coordinate shift" is not constant or linear, but it is a "jump"

Comment: Well, I kind of tried to describe it this way at the beginning.. It's not just a jump when there is no jump mouse cursor displaced anywhay most of the time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was scaling problem after all. One of the scale values were negative and was causing this behaviour.